# Split column multiple values of an SQL 2005 table into new columns of a new temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm facing a situation where a customers table with more that 150000 records have a column with phone numbers which contains more than one values (phones) separated by spaces, commas, dashes, dots, etc. The original column values are varchar type max 30. I need a way to check these values and split them into equal columns of a new table and then normalize them by removing any special characters from inside them. None of the new columns values should have more that 10 digits.

Find below a select query results of the current table which clearly depicts the current mess. Column No_ (`ΠΕxxxxxx`) is the `Customer Unique Identifier`. Column `Phone No_` is the messy one

```
 - List item

-**No_**        **Phone No_**
-ΠΕ000586   2310836590
-ΠΕ000589   2310.443602/6977.226818
-ΠΕ000591   2310740215
-ΠΕ000593   2310228976
-ΠΕ000598   2310444604
-ΠΕ000606   2310265616/6939686560
-ΠΕ000611   2310.227932(AΔΕΡΦΗ ΚΟΚΚΑΛΑ)
-ΠΕ000621   2310826921/6979552442
-ΠΕ000626   2310846216
-ΠΕ000629   2310931574
-ΠΕ000630   6977629688, 2310320441
-ΠΕ000631   2310.260886/6973.999840
-ΠΕ000633   2310.288408/342456/6944.503637
-ΠΕ000636   2310440143/6978008313
-ΠΕ000637   2310425655/6945365400
-ΠΕ000646   944111072
-ΠΕ000652   2310.201923,6942.693372
-ΠΕ000667   2310.482194/6977394456
-ΠΕ000675   6949199051
```

Each number separated by **/,- or space** must be separated into new columns

Any text must be removed.

Any number sequence with less than `10` digits, if the sequence have `6` digits a **2310** prefix must be added, if the sequence have `9` digits and the **first digit** of the sequence starts with **9**, number `6` must be added as **prefix**. 
For Example

```
the number 342456 must become 2310342456 and the number 944111072 must become 694411072
```

Any dot(.) between numbers sequence of 10 digits must be removed in order to have one unique number 
For Example

```
the number 231.282414 must be 231282414 or 6942.693372 must be 6942693372
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Why does your question read like a requirements specification document?

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
if object_id('splitNums') is not null
    drop function splitNums
go

create function splitNums(@nums varchar(30))
returns @tr table (n1 varchar(10), n2 varchar(10), n3 varchar(10), n4 varchar(10), n5 varchar(10)) as
begin
    declare @v varchar(10)
    declare @i int
    insert into @tr values (null, null, null, null, null)
    declare @ci int = 1
    while (@ci <= 5 ) begin
        if ( LEN(@nums) > 0 ) begin
            set @i = charindex('/', @nums)
            if ( @i <= 0 )
                set @i = charindex(' ', @nums)
            if ( @i <= 0 )
                set @i = charindex('-', @nums)
            if ( @i <= 0) begin
                set @v = @nums 
                set @nums = ''
            end else begin
                set @v = SUBSTRING(@nums, 1, @i - 1)
                set @nums = SUBSTRING(@nums, @i + 1, len(@nums) - @i)
            end
        end else set @v = ''
        if ( @v = '' ) break
        set @v = replace(@v, '.', '') -- more code needed here to remove text
        if ( len(@v) = 6 ) set @v = '2310' + @v
        else if (len(@v) = 9 and CHARINDEX('9', @v) = 1) set @v = '6' + @v
        -- impossible to do dynamic sql in function so...
        if (@ci = 1)
            update @tr set n1 = @v
        else if (@ci = 2)
            update @tr set n2 = @v
        else if (@ci = 3)
            update @tr set n3 = @v
        else if (@ci = 4)
            update @tr set n4 = @v
        else if (@ci = 5)
            update @tr set n5 = @v
        set @ci = @ci + 1
    end
    return
end
go

declare @t table (
    id nvarchar(10),
    number nvarchar(30)
)

insert into @t (id, number) values
   (N'ΠΕ000586', '2310836590'),
   (N'ΠΕ000589', '2310.443602/6977.226818'),
   (N'ΠΕ000633', '2310.288408/342456/6944.503637')

select * from @t cross apply dbo.splitNums(number)
go
```

Comment: Great! Thx a million for the time you save me

Comment: I'm sorry if the reading is not the proper one. Probably I had to rephrase it before post it. I'm new to this area and I will surely try to express my issues in a more acceptable way.

Comment: I hadn't tried anything like your code. Just simple update-replace queries where each time I had to change the searching character, symbol, etc; Your code gave me a more bulk solution. Once again thx a lot.